# Dragdrop from listbox to listbox in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, listbox, drag-and-drop

I am using a listbox to bind the data coming from the database, once the binding is done there is another listbox where i have to drag and drop the contents of the first listbox. I am able to drag and drop it but nothing is visible in the 2nd listbox(but the content is moving from the 1st to 2nd listbox). The same thing i tried by hardcoding the items in the 1st listbox and everything worked fine. If anybody has experienced similar kind of problem, please help.

Comment: maybe you should paste some code with edit your post

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using ObservableCollection when dragging and dropping between sources. If you used List, then the ListBoxes will not be notified of a change in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle ondrop event of second listbox and you will have to update the collection that is binded to the second listbox in the drop event.